# How to set setOnClickListner on ViewHolder and use Intent to start a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Expandable ListView and want to start a new Activity on onClick but it is showing error when I am trying to start an activity by using Intent.

```
public class ArtistViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

  private TextView childTextView;

  public ArtistViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    childTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_name);
    childTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        // I want to start a new Activity here.. but it is showing error!

        startActivity(new Intent(ArtistViewHolder.this, VideoViewActivity.class));
      }
    });
  }

  public void setArtistName(String name) {
    childTextView.setText(name);
  }
}
```

Here is my ChildViewHolder class :

```
public class ChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public ChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @W4R10CK it is showing error at this line :  startActivity(new Intent(ArtistViewHolder.this, VideoViewActivity.class));

Comment: add your error log in the question. [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have activity instance into adpater?? Show us your adapter initialization code.

Comment: in adapter we need to use Context object.before startActivity.

Comment: @SalmanShaikh..you solved it..?

Comment: Please check again..Ans updated....Now replace my all code

Comment: @SagarAghara no..  
it is showing error (red line) under startActivity

Comment: just show me your constructor, your constructor is not getting your activity. when you call adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No Big Change here just two world**

```
   itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), VideoViewActivity.class));
```

Comment: still showing redline under startActivity - Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)'

Comment: itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), VideoViewActivity.class));   This worked thanks!

Comment: Ohhh..Great answer.

Comment: @SagarAghara I already voted the answer but due to less reputation points it will not display. It needs 15 points to rate.

Comment: i don't need help from this Question...but i will voteUp your Question.because of  @ sushant gosavi 's answer...bcz i learned new using this Que.

Answer (score 3):

**Replace** below code with Your code :

```
public class ArtistViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

  private TextView childTextView;

  public ArtistViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    childTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_name);
    childTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        itemView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(itemView.getContext(), VideoViewActivity.class));
      }
    });
  }

  public void setArtistName(String name) {
    childTextView.setText(name);
  }
}
```

Please check this and let me know.

Hope this will helps you...(:

Comment: I replaced the code but it is showing error (red line) under (ArtistViewHolder.this, VideoViewActivity.class)

Comment: still same issue.. showing redline under (ArtistViewHolder.this, VideoViewActivity.class)

Comment: now..move your cursor in your RedLine....and see what error...and tell us....without that we can't Understand your problem.

Comment: i think..you extends your own class[ChildViewHolder]..that is why it shown Red line.

Comment: Hey...i made an adapter for you in my project..yes it also shown Redline error to me....

Comment: you can not use OnClickListener() into your Constructor.

Comment: Sager ArtistViewHolder.this   is just a class you cannot pass as context(coz ArtistViewHolder is not a Activity not having its context )

Comment: Thanks to you too...Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You should startActivity with a context.
Replace   `startActivity(new Intent(ArtistViewHolder.this, VideoViewActivity.class));`

with `startActivity(new Intent(mContext, VideoViewActivity.class));`

where `mContext` is the context which you pass to your adapter while creating it.